# Let client add data to Firestore through HTTP POST cloud function (Architecture)

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm building a web shop using Firestore and Firebase for the first time, I'm also new to NoSQL. I have the following architectural problem: When a customer places an order the client sends the products ordered to Firestore directly which stores the order in a collection `raw_orders`. My idea then was to have a Cloud Function trigger on the document create which processes it and builds an invoice and such. However I read that this function invocation may be delayed for 10 seconds, I would like to have a synchronous solution instead.

Instead I had the idea to create a HTTP Cloud Function where the customer can POST the order to, the HTTP function then processes the order and pushes it to Firestore, the function then returns the orderID or something to the customer. This approach feels much more safe since the user won't have to talk to the database directly. Also it solves the issues that the a function triggered by a Firestore create might be delayed.

However I'm new to Firebase and I'm not sure if this is architecturally the preferred way. The method I propose seems to be more in line with regular old REST APIs.

What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you definitely have some server-side code and database operations that you can't trust the clients to do.  (Keep in mind that firestore security rules are your only protection -- anyone can run whatever code they want within those rules, not just the code you provide).

Cloud functions give you exactly this -- and since you both want the operation to be synchronous (from the view of your client) and presumably have some way for the client to react to errors in the process, a cloud function would make a lot of sense for you to use.

Using cloud functions in this way is very common in Firebase apps, even if it isn't pure REST.

Moreover, if you are using Firebase more generally in your client, it might be more natural to use a [callable cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) rather than an http function, as this will handle the marshaling of the parameters in a much more native way than a raw HTTP request might.  However, it isn't clear in your case since it sounds like you're using the REST API today.

Keep in mind that there are [additional costs](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) (or specific quotas, depending on your pricing plan) for running cloud functions.  The pricing is based on invocations, as well as CPU and RAM usage of your functions.